# T - SQL variable programming like in R/C++

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, t-sql

I have sql data of 2,907,735 rows and 32 columns.. and I want to perform simple mathematical calculations for each row using the attributes in that row.

Currently, I had to program this in R which is taking so much time, and I'm not sure SQL has the capability to do this simple programming calculations are not.
If it has the capability, I think SQL will be faster. 
**Please help.**

```
q1=0
q2=0
q3=0
q4=0
frac2final=0
sumcnt = 0
cumcnt = 0 
year = 0
startpoint1 = 0 
startpoint2 = 0 
sumexpect = 0
cntatmind = 0
cntatmaxd = 0
exatmind = 0
exatmaxd = 0
ex1=0
ex2=0
ex3=0
ex4=0
cumcntfirst = 0


for (i in 1:2907735)

{

  frac2final = a[i,25]
  sumcnt = a[i,31]
  cumcnt = frac2final + sumcnt
  year = a[i,12]
  sumexpect = a[i,32]
  cntatmind = a[i,4]
  cntatmaxd = a[i,5]
  exatmind = a[i,6]
  exatmaxd = a[i,7]


  if(year !=2016) {
    startpoint1 = 0 
    startpoint2=0} 
  else 
    {startpoint1 = frac2final 
      startpoint2 = frac2final}

  #cumcntfirst = startpoint2 + cntatmind



  if (startpoint1<=0.25)  q1 = max( (min(0.25,cumcnt) - startpoint1),0) else q1=0
  startpoint1 = startpoint1 + q1

  if(startpoint1<=0.5) q2 = max( (min(0.5,cumcnt) - startpoint1),0) else q2=0
  startpoint1 = startpoint1 + q2

  if(startpoint1<=0.75) q3 = max( (min(0.75,cumcnt) - startpoint1),0) else q3=0
  startpoint1 = startpoint1 + q3

  q4 = max(0,sumcnt-q1-q2-q3)





  a[i,33] = q1 
  a[i,34] = q2 
  a[i,35] = q3 
  a[i,36] = q4 



}
```

Comment: Yes, SQL can do mathematical calculations. It can also do them conditionally based on expressions and/or values from the row (look at `CASE`).

Comment: I tried case  but  I want to perform max(min(a, max(b,c),d) kind of calculations  and want to use to intermediate results for further calculations

Comment: That may be a bit more difficult, but possible. Some combination of R and SQL will probably work. Bottom line though, no one is going to go through your R and extract your logic then turn it around into a SQL query for you (well maybe someone is extra bored & generous today). You will probably need to describe the logic you need and attempt a SQL query if you want a solid answer here.

Comment: SQL Server can perform such calculations on millions of rows very fast if you write the proper set-based query. It's NOT a matrix calculation library. R can *also* work fast if you use vectorized operations instead of loops. Perhaps you should fix your R script first

Comment: Please look at the calculations for q1,q2,q3,q4

Answer (score 1):

Remember in SQL we work with sets, not loops. An "Intermediate result" would be an in intermediate result **set**, which is synonymous with a subquery (for the most part).

As an example using your R as a starting point:

```
SELECT q1,
    startpoint1 + q1 AS startpoint1
FROM (
    startpoint1,
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN startpoint1 <= 0.25
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN 0 > CASE 
                                WHEN 0.25 > cumcnt
                                    THEN 0.25
                                ELSE cumcnt
                                END - startpoint1
                            THEN 0
                        ELSE CASE 
                                WHEN 0.25 > cumcnt
                                    THEN 0.25
                                ELSE cumcnt
                                END - startpoint1
                        END
            ELSE 0
            END AS q1

    FROM (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN year <> 2016
                    THEN 0
                ELSE frac2final
                END AS startpoint1,
            CASE 
                WHEN year <> 2016
                    THEN 0
                ELSE frac2final
                END AS startpoint2
        FROM yourTable
        ) subquery1
    ) subquery2
```

There is no function to replicate your `min` and `max` here so we have to use CASE statements to do the logic. There are many examples of UDFs out there to give this functionality though. The trick is that `min` and `max` DO exist in tsql, but it takes the min/max of values in a column when aggregating many records together. Your use here is synonymous with UDFs generally called `GREATEST()` and `LEAST()` to compare two or more fields from the same record.

To get a grasp on how this is working, run the inner-most subquery and see what it produces, then run the next subquery (which has subquery1 inside of it) to see how it uses those results... then you can just reuse this logic to build your remaining fields for your final result set.